# Making R2D2 sounds with Korg iMS20 or Korg DS10

Tags: sound-effects, synthesizer, replication

I'm going to be playing a Star Wars RPG and was hoping to have a little audio prop for added effect.

I have an iPad and old Nintendo DSi with some Korg apps and Kaos Pads would do the trick, but my tinkering hasn't nailed the sound yet.

Comment: the r2d2 sounds are not only synthesized, ben burtt also pitched his own voice with sampler and a keyboard.